# How to break a while loop in Kivy?

Tags: android, python-2.7, while-loop, kivy

Here I have a function runStuff that I would like to keep running the function saySomething() repeatedly but will exit upon the pressing of the exit button.

It is currently running the while loop without allowing the input of the exit button.

```
def saySomething():
    ttsSpeak('Say this phrase')

def runStuff(self):
    while True:
        if App.get_running_app().stop() != True:
            saySomething()
            time.sleep(2)
        else: break

def exit(self):
    App.get_running_app().stop()

class AudibleCoachApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=7, spacing=3, orientation='vertical') # set layout of the screen
        btn1 = Button(text='Start it', size_hint=(1, .66)) # create a button instance
        btn1.bind(on_press=runStuff) # binding the button with the function below
        btn3 = Button(text='Exit', size_hint=(1, .17)) # create a button instance
        btn3.bind(on_press=exit) # binding the button with the function below
        layout.add_widget(btn1) # physically add the button onto the layout
        layout.add_widget(btn2) # physically add the button onto the layout
        layout.add_widget(btn3) # physically add the button onto the layout 

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AudibleCoachApp().run()
```

Comment: What did you really mean to call instead of `stop()` in your while loop condition? It looks like you're looking for something that tells you if your app is stopping?

Comment: Not too sure about your question. I want runStuff() to keep calling saySomething() as long as the exit button is not pressed. When the exit button is pressed, I want it to execute the exit function.

Comment: Right, well, you call `stop()` in two different places, and you seem to be hoping it will do something completely different in each spot. In one spot you want it to stop your program. In the other you want it to check if you've stopped the program. But you call it in the exact same way, and Python can't read your mind. So one of those calls has to be wrong…that's all I was saying.

Comment: I am new to kivy, little confused as to how to activate the stop() in the runStuff() loop.

Comment: You're probably seeing problems because you put a loop with `time.sleep()` in your callback function. If you want to run something every X seconds, it looks like you should use a [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works partially that it can exit but for some reason even without pressing the start button the function starts itself. "btn1.bind(on_press=Clock.schedule_interval(runStuff, 0.5))", "def runStuff(dt):saySomething()"

Comment: Never mind, got it to work "Clock.schedule_interval(saySomething, 0.5)
" should be in the function not call from button. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite loops are rarely a good solution in UI programming, because they block the entire thread that they are running on. It would be better to use kivy's `Clock` object to schedule your method.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

def runStuff(self):
    Clock.schedule(saySomething, 2)
```

The callback can then be unscheduled using `Clock.unschedule`.

```
def exit(self):
    App.get_running_app().stop()
    Clock.unschedule(saySomething)
```

Additionally, the use of `get_running_app` is generally discouraged, since it is good practice to have all functions with access to the app to be methods of the app. Since you included `self` arguments in each of the functions, I assume that is what you were planning to do anyway.

```
class AudibleCoachApp(App):

    def runStuff(self):
        Clock.schedule(saySomething, 2)

    def exit(self):
        Clock.unschedule(saySomething)
        self.stop()
```

You'll have to change your call of `runStuff` and `exit` in `build` to `self.runStuff` and `self.exit`.

```
btn1.bind(on_press=self.runStuff) # binding the button with the function
```

...

```
btn3.bind(on_press=self.exit) # binding the button with the function below
```

And, you'll need to explicitly bind the app to stop the `Clock` from being GC'd.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = AudibleCoachApp()
    app.run()
```

Altogether, the code becomes the following (don't forget to add the import of `Clock` from `kivy.clock`).

```
import pyttsx
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

# ...

def saySomething():
    ttsSpeak('Say this phrase')

class AudibleCoachApp(App):

    def runStuff(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(saySomething, 2)

    def exit(self):
        Clock.unschedule(saySomething)
        self.stop()

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=7, spacing=3, orientation='vertical') # set layout of the screen
        btn1 = Button(text='Start it', size_hint=(1, .66)) # create a button instance
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.runStuff) # binding the button with the function below
        btn2 = Button()
        btn3 = Button(text='Exit', size_hint=(1, .17)) # create a button instance
        btn3.bind(on_press=self.exit) # binding the button with the function below
        layout.add_widget(btn1) # physically add the button onto the layout
        layout.add_widget(btn2) # physically add the button onto the layout
        layout.add_widget(btn3) # physically add the button onto the layout 

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = AudibleCoachApp()
    app.run()
```

NOTE that all the code above is untested. If you spot any errors, please leave a comment.